# trying to link to index.html from another html page deeper in the folder structure

Tags: html, anchor

I'm trying to get something basic to work here. I have an index page in my root and another folder called collections. Within collections, I have another folder 'MA' that has 'MA.html'. All I want to do is link MA.html back to index.html. I have an anchor link 'back' that tries to do so but on clicking it just reloads MA.html again. I'm still new to web dev so go pls go easy on me. I am adding an image of my folder structure.

[image]

Here is my HTML -

```
<div class="info overlay">
     <div class="text">
        <a href="/collections/MA/MA.html">MA</a>
        <a href="/collections/capsule.html">Capsule</a>
        <a href="/collections/BA/BA.html">BA</a>
     </div>
     <a href="/index.html" class="info-back">Back</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: SO when I click on 'back' the url does change to index.html for a second but it redirects back to collections/MA

Comment: `href="/index.html"` should indeed link to the `index.html` that's in the root of the site.  Can you show what the URL is when you're looking at the `MA.html` file and what the URL is when you're looking at the `index.html` file in your browser?

Comment: ok so URL when looking at MA.html - http://127.0.0.1:5501/collections/MA/MA.html and URL when looking at index.html is - http://127.0.0.1:5501/index.html

Comment: if index is your homepage, you should just put `/` instead of `/index.html`

Comment: Then I'm not able to replicate the behavior described.  When you use your browser's debugging tools, what specifically happens upon clicking the link?  When you hover over the link, what preview URL displays in the status bar?  What is the address requested by the browser?  Does it go to `index.html` but then get redirected back to `MA.html`?  There's something else going on here that's not included in the question.

Comment: So when I hover over 'back' the preview url shows /index.html. On clicking back - the main url changes to index.html for a second and then goes back to collections/\MA.html

Comment: @LaiqaMohid: Then something is happening on `index.html` that's causing the redirect.  Is there any JavaScript on that page which performs a redirect?

Comment: when I am on index.html and click on the link to take me to ma.html it works fine

Comment: Okay yes you were right, I was using barba.js that was screwing everything up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In index.html**

```
<a href="./collections/MA/MA.html">MA</a>
```

That's the same as before, once you land on MA.html, you want to go back to index.html So-

**In MA.html**

```
<a href="../../index.html">link</a>
```

The `..` (double dots) mean 'go up a directory level'.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing / before calling the directory

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="./collections/MA/MA.html">redirect</a>
```

This will let you connect index.html with MA.html.